# Set styles dynamically in javascript

Tags: javascript, styles, set

I have to set margin dynamically to an element. Earlier it was done by like following.

```
var starLink = star.createChild({
            tag: 'a',
            html: this.values[i],
            href: 'javascript:void',           
            title: this.showTitles ? this.titles[i] : ''
        });

        // Prepare division settings
        if(this.split) {
          var odd = (i % this.split);              
          star.setWidth(sw);
          starLink.setStyle('margin-left', '-' + (odd * sw) + 'px');          
        }
```

But now I changed my code as below. How will I set the margin here?

```
var starLink = document.createElement('a');        
        starLink.href = 'javascript:void';         
        starLink.title = this.showTitles ? this.titles[i] : '';
        starLink.innerHTML = this.values[i];
        star.appendChild(starLink);

 // Prepare division settings
        if(this.split) {
          var odd = (i % this.split);              
          star.setWidth(sw);
          starLink.setStyle('margin-left', '-' + (odd * sw) + 'px');              
        }
```

Comment: element.style.margin or maybe you should use setAttribute method?

Comment: I tried. But dont find the correct method. Could you please give me a sample code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
var starLink = document.createElement('a');        
starLink.href = 'javascript:void';         
starLink.title = this.showTitles ? this.titles[i] : '';
starLink.innerHTML = this.values[i];
star.appendChild(starLink);

// Prepare division settings
if(this.split) {
    var odd = (i % this.split);              
    star.setWidth(sw);
    starLink.style.marginLeft = '-' + (odd * sw) + 'px';              
}
```

Answer (score 2):

starLink.style.marginLeft='10px'
or 
starLink.style.margin = "0px 0px 0px " + xOffset + "px";